# How to Store cookies upon an action of login and retrieve cookies inside a <s:textfield /> tag in any of the jsp pages

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, cookies

I am new to cookies management.
I just want to start with a simple scenario. When user successfully login to his account a uid (which is fetched from the uid of the corresponding row in Users table from database) is generated and stored on the hard disk of the user system as a cookie. After login user is redirected to his home page. User go to another accessible page say myinfo.jsp. myinfo.jsp contains a textfield in which the uid to be displayed which is to be retrieved form the cookies stored on harddisk. I want when a user navigates to myinfo.jsp he should see his uid in the textfield.

I am using J2EE technologies.

Can someone suggest a way how to do this simple task. Or can someone please put some `to the point to my this simple task` tutorial's link. I ll be thankfull for any help or hint. Thanks.

Comment: Can some one solve this problem as well.. thanks.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641662/doccookie-is-not-getting-saved-instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the value of the textfield in the action class that is rendering the jsp. If you are using a session manager to store active logins you can do the following.

```
User user = (User)request.getSession().getAttribute("userAttributeName");
setTextField(user.getId().toString)
```

else you can get the cookie and iterate in your code to get the attribute needed.

```
public static String getCookieValue(String cookieName, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String cookieVal = null;
    Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();
    if(null != cookies && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(cookieName))
    {
        for(Cookie cookie : cookies)
        {
            if(cookieName.equals(cookie.getName()))
            {
                cookieVal = cookie.getValue();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieVal;
}

String userId = getCookieValue(cookieName, request);
setTextField(user.getId().toString);
```

You can also get the cookie using Jquery (javascript). [This link](http://www.jquery4u.com/data-manipulation/jquery-set-delete-cookies/) might help.

Comment: Hi arvind.. i wish NOT to implement any action class for this simple task. But i only want to retrieve the uid from the cookie. Can u plz help me out with reference to cookie management. however i want to use the action class only to login and generate uid.

Comment: @Rambo - pls see the edited answer... have provided a javascript alternative also.

Comment: Ok thanku so much for your answer. Please also help me out "how to store the uid as a cookie on the harddisk"